# Memoir: Small caps section number in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, small-caps

I would like appendices to be numbered using small caps in my `memoir` document. I have managed to do it for the actual title, but I can't seem to figure out how I should fix the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}[
  BoldFont = EBGaramond-Bold,
  Numbers={Proportional, OldStyle}
]
\setsecnumformat{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\csname the#1\endcsname}}\quad}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents*

  \chapter{A chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}
  \begin{subappendices}
    \section{An appendix}
  \end{subappendices}

  \chapter{Second chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table of contents]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\numberline{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum}{\@cftbsnum{#1}\@cftasnum}{}{\ERROR}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\cftsectionpresnum{\scshape\MakeLowercase}
```